# onload function with div

Tags: events, html

Is it valid to use onload function with **div** element.

Comment: Test it, tell us - show the code.

Things like this are the subject of detailed specs, which are rarely fully 100% functional, plus how exactly do you  want to use onload?

Comment: i'm already tested but its not working. is any other way to call a function on loading particular div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/):

> [The [onload](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onload)] attribute may be
>   used with BODY and FRAMESET elements.

The short answer to your question, then, is 'no' (at least if you want to constrain yourself to standard behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of -- such behavior would likely be fairly hard to define.

Just do whatever you want to do to the div ondomready (or whatever event your favorite javascript utility library provides).